# I got Bad input shape

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

When I use the following code

```
df_reclamos_transf = df6

X = df_reclamos_transf.drop(['CATEGORIA'], axis=1)
y = df_reclamos_transf['CATEGORIA']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

labels = df_reclamos_transf['CATEGORIA']
encoder = LabelEncoder() 
encoder.fit(labels)

for i, item in enumerate(encoder.classes_):
    print(item, '=>',i)

X_train = encoder.fit_transform(X_train)  
X_test = encoder.transform(X_test)
```

```
~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in column_or_1d(y, warn)
    795         return np.ravel(y)
    796 
--> 797     raise ValueError("bad input shape {0}".format(shape))
    798 
    799 

ValueError: bad input shape (126527, 5)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! For us to help you better, please post some sample data and be clear in what you think is wrong and what you expect the output to be. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
encoder1 = LabelEncoder() 
X_train = encoder1.fit_transform(X_train)  
X_test = encoder1.transform(X_test)
```

Try running this. You created an encoder and fitted it on `labels`. Then you are using the same encoder for `X_train` which is of different shape which might cause this issue. Create a new `LabelEncoder` object and try it.

Comment: How is this different from the original code and why does it solve the problem?

Comment: The encoder is fitted on labels and then it is again fitting on X_train which might cause this issue. I havent confirmed it by running it myself to check but from what I see in the question, this seems like the only issue.